# Why Caption on the button doesn't change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why When I press the button the caption doesn't change to 'Hide details' despite   Name=false ?

```
let Name= true;

const Tekst= () =>{

 Name=false;
Render();

};

const template = (

<div>
<h1>Visibility Toggle</h1>
<button onClick={Tekst}>{Name ? 'Show details' : 'Hide details'}</button>        
</div>
);


const root= document.getElementById('app');

const Render = () =>ReactDOM.render(template, root);

Render();
```

Comment: your template is a bunch of static jsx, you should make it a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kindly note that your template jsx is hard coded and is only evaluated once when the program runs initially. So it just takes value of `Name` as `true` and becomes a constant. Rendering it again is not going to change in any way. You should use a component rather:

```
<Template />
```

```js
let Name = true;

const Tekst = () => {
  Name = !Name;
  Render();
};

const Template = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Visibility Toggle</h1>
    <button onClick={Tekst}>
      {Name ? "Show details" : "Hide details"}
    </button>
  </div>
);

const root = document.getElementById("app");

const Render = () => ReactDOM.render(<Template />, root);

Render();
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: my answer is for that only

Comment: yes using the code i have provided , show deatails will change to hide details. did you run it ?

Comment: This is correct answer, ignore the previous comments arguing. The issue was that the template was evaluated only once while the script was loaded. But you want to evaluate it every time you render, thus you had to change it to a function: note `const Template = () => `. and `ReactDOM.render(<Template/>,`

Comment: To add to my previous comment, this answer explains the issue with your code. But it is not a React way of doing it. Look at code in the @Jonathan-Rys answer to see a nicer way to do this.

Comment: absolutely,that crossed my mind,  but he might be trying to start with react , let him reach class Components in his own time

Comment: i think can edit , will do in 2-3 minutes.. thanks for suggesting

Comment: it was not a function earlier

Comment: Why `ReactDom.render()` is wrapped into a function `Render`? What is this bringing into the table?

Comment: look at the code of OP from a perspective of a beginner, and thats why i dont want to review the code for good practices. OP has asked a nice question and has given a very nice code sample to reproduce the problem

Comment: @ashishsingh Ok Fine. Then teach the OP also if you want, what is needed and what doesn't make any sense.. He could do `import { render } from 'react-dom'`, and use that too.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do that:

```js
    
    class Template extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        
        this.state = {name: true};
      }

      test = () => {
        this.setState({name: !this.state.name});
      };
      
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>Visibility Toggle</h1>
            <button onClick={this.test}>{this.state.name ? 'Show details' : 'Hide details'}</button>        
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
    
ReactDOM.render(
  <Template/>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because a component only renders when state or props change.
The way you defined your component, it has no props or state.

Try:

```
class Tekst extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { Name: true };
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  }

  toggle() {
    this.setState({ Name: !this.state.Name });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Visibility Toggle</h1>
        <button onClick={this.toggle}>{ this.state.Name ? 'Show details' : 'Hide details'} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm not sure which version of react or env you're on but this should work for most setups.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the OP has a very limited understanding of React. This is not a criticism, we all have to start somewhere (and I would not consider myself much above beginner-level with React :) ). But if you want to make something with React, even just a toy example, I would strongly recommended reading through the introductory documentation at https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html and the subsequent pages. In particular, I draw your attention to the following:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html#updating-the-rendered-element (which explains why when a "React element" such as yours is rendered, it can never be updated except by re-rendering).
- https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components explains the basics of React Components, explaining that you need either a function or (for most non-trivial components) an ES6 Class. Once you have a React component, it will automatically re-render when its Props or State are altered. (As Salomao noted, your application contains neither.)